# Integer range and multiple of

Tags: regex

I have a number of fields I want to validate on text entry with a regex for both matching a range (0..120) and must be a multiple of 5.

For example, 0, 5, 25, 120 are valid. 1, 16, 123, 130 are not valid.

I think I have the regex for multiple of 5:

```
^\d*\d?((5)|(0))\.?((0)|(00))?$
```

and the regex for the range:

```
120|1[01][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]
```

However, I dont know how to combine these, any help much appreciated!

Comment: Regex is not what you want. What language are you using?

Comment: `regex` works fine for divisibility with 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** added another `regex` (see below) to be used when the range of values is not `0`..`120` (it can even be dynamic).

---

The second `regex` in the question does not match numbers smaller than 20. You can change it to match smaller numbers that always end in `0` or `5` to be multiple by `5`:

```
\b(120|(1[01]|[0-9])?[05])\b
```

#### How it works (starting from inside):

- `(1[01]|[0-9])?` matches `10`, `11` or any one-digit number (`0` to `9`); these are the hundreds and tens in the final number; the question mark (`?`) after the sub-expression makes it match 0 or 1 times; this way the regex can also match numbers having only one digit (`0`..`9`);
- `[05]` that follows matches `0` or `5` on the last digit (the units); only the numbers that end in `0` or `5` are multiple of `5`;
- everything is enclosed in parenthesis because `|` has greater priority than `\b`;
- the outer `\b` matches word boundaries; they prevent the regex match only 1..3 digits from a longer number or numbers that are embedded in strings; it prevents it matching `15` in `150` or `120` in `abc120`.

#### Using dynamic range of values

The `regex` above is not very complex and it can be used to match numbers between `0` and `120` that are multiple of `5`. When the range of values is different it cannot be used any more. It can be modified to match, lets say, numbers between `20` and `120` (as the OP asked in a comment below) but it will become harder to read.

More, if the range of allowed values is dynamic then a `regex` cannot be used at all to match the values inside the range. The multiplicity with `5` however can be achieved using `regex` :-)

For dynamic range of values that are multiple of `5` you can use this expression:

```
\b([1-9][0-9]*)?[05]\b
```

Parse the matched string as integer (the language you use probably provides such a function or a library that contains it) then use the comparison operators (`<`, `>`) of the host language to check if the matched value is inside the desired range.

Comment: You seem to be able to enter any multiple of 5 over 120 with this? Also, if I were to require a range of say 20-120, then would you replace 1[01]|[0-9] with 1[01]|[2-9]?

Comment: No, it doesn't match numbers greater than `120`. You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/zL1hO9/1). It works because the domain of values is fixed and it can be easily expressed using a regular expression. If you need a dynamic range then you better use `\b([1-9][0-9]*)?[05]\b` then check the matched value against the boundaries using the language comparison operators (`<` and `>`).

Comment: Updated the answer with a section about dynamic range of values (or any range, not just `0`..`120`).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with a simple regex. At least not the range-part (especially if the range should be generic/changeable).

And even if you manage to write the regex, it will be very complex and unreadable.

Write the validation on your own, using a `parseStringToInt()` function of your language and simple `<` and `>` checks.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being painfully obvious

```
120|1[01][05]|[2-9][05]
```

Also, why the 2?

Comment: This doesn't match 15, or 10.

Comment: It's because of the 2 in his example, it looked deliberate as if he's looking for numbers greater than 19. If you want as worded replace [2-9] with [1-9]? With the question mark

Comment: This still suffers from problems, it'll match `150` as well.